# return async tcp data

Tags: flutter, dart, tcp, tcpclient

I have a function, that send async  tcp request to server and wait first response from stream. Everything working fine, but for some reason in the end when function returns response function just stops and await of this func just stops too

in repository where i need get response i am calling and doing await of AuthCreds (but execution just stops in await)

````
    Future<AuthCredentialsResponse> AuthCreds(
      AuthCredentialsRequest request) async {
    return await handleMessage(request.Marshal()) as AuthCredentialsResponse;
  }

  Future<Message> handleMessage(Uint8List data) async {
    TcpBloc tcpBloc = TcpBloc(keyStore: keyStore);

    onEncryptEnabled() {
      tcpBloc.sendMessage(SendMessage(message: data));
    }

    StreamController streamController = StreamController();

    Stream responseStream = streamController.stream;

    tcpBloc.connect(
        onEncryptEnabled,
        streamController,
        Connect(
            host: connectParams.host,
            port: connectParams.port,
            encryptionEnabled: connectParams.isEncryptionEnabled));

    var firstValueReceived = Completer<Uint8List>();

    responseStream.listen((event) {
      if (!firstValueReceived.isCompleted) {
        firstValueReceived.complete(event);
      }
    });

    Uint8List rawResponse = await firstValueReceived.future;

    tcpBloc.close();

    return getResponse(rawResponse);
  }

  Message getResponse(Uint8List rawResponse) {
    int lastMethodNameIndex = getLastMethodNameIndex(rawResponse);
    String methodName =
        String.fromCharCodes(rawResponse.sublist(0, lastMethodNameIndex));

    Uint8List body = rawResponse.sublist(lastMethodNameIndex + 1);
    Message response = GetResponse(methodName, body);
    return response;
  }```
````

Comment: What is a TcpBloc and why does it need a stream, when only the first event is important?

Comment: @nvoigt tcpbloc need for interaction with raw tcp socket with my custom encryption and another things. tcp bloc universal class and in some cases i need many data, anyway it is listening from stream in default implementation of raw tcp sockets in flutter.

But question not about this, tcp bloc works fine, i just dont understand why final value that i already got from stream is not returning upside to repository

Comment: I'm asking because normally with tcp and streams you are supposed to wait until the stream is finished, if you just use the first bytes, you may not have a complete message if the message is bigger. But maybe you handled that in TcpBloc, I don't know. The rest looks okay at first glance. What does `GetResponse` do and why are you sure it returns an `AuthCredentialsResponse`?

Comment: Also, a `Future<AuthCredentialsResponse>` cannot return "nothing". What happens in the line where you call it?

Comment: @nvoigt i am sending length of full message in first bytes and separate them after. GetResponse method returns response class based on methodName got from message, it is look kinda that
https://pastebin.com/emvGn8TK
this func returns everything as expected

Comment: Well, you already seem to know what works as expected, maybe give us a little hint what *doesn't*? Which line do you have problems with?

Comment: @nvoight repo func where i call AuthCreds https://pastebin.com/3fKcQ0RD

Comment: @nvoight my problem is that after handleMessage returns final value await just stop execution and not getting any value from handeMessage func and i dont know why

Comment: If it stops execution, you surely get an error message. Look at your console or logs or stack. It doesn't "just stop" with not feedback.

Comment: @nvoight program is not exit, i mean await continue waiting return value from handleMessage func after return. After a long wait (~30sec) i am getting only message about server forcibly closed connection

Comment: What do you mean after "return"? How do you know it did reach the "return"?

Comment: @nvoight i checked in debugger that program reached this line return getResponse(await firstValueReceived.future); and i seen that await firstValueReceived.future returned some value and getResponse successfully returned response object

Comment: So what did it return? Was it an `AuthCredentialsResponse` as expected? Consider putting in some print statements when you handle TCP work, since there are timeouts in play you might accidentially trip when looking at things with a debugger for "too long" (seconds...).

Comment: @nvoight ohhh... i got it.. i just named method AuthCredentials instead of AuthCreds, sorry
Thank you for helping!